# Flask, getting error `TypeError: jsonify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj' // Werkzeug Debugger`

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

This is my code, route where the process happens and model where I connect to MySQL DB

Route

```py
@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    names = request.json['name']
    email = request.json['email']
    password = request.json['password']

    new_user = User(names, email, password)

    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return UserSchema.jsonify(new_user)
```

**Model Schema**

```py
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'names', 'email', 'image_file', 'status', 'archived', 'admin', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

The data get saved to database but response gives error

Comment: Can you show some more detail about the error (e.g. line number and full stack trace)

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you do `return UserSchema.jsonify(new_user)` then with *new_user* object you are also trying to expose the password field.

And as you can see you haven't set `password` to be exposed in the fields tuple of Meta class.

```
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'names', 'email', 'image_file', 'status', 'archived', 'admin', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```